# Summation of all j-combinations (Expanding composition formula)

Tags: combinatorics

I found a formula for a problem that I was trying to solve, the Formula 3.2 in Section 3 at page 441 of this [document](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf).I am a little unsure about the "Summation over all j-combinations". Here is what I think but I am unsure about it. For example for k=3

$$\begin{align*}F(n,k;h_1,p_1;h_2,p_2;h_3,p_3)&=\binom{n-h+k-1}{k-1}+(-1)^1\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_1-h_1)}{k-1}+(-1)^2\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_1-h_1)-(p_2-h_2)}{k-1}+(-1)^3\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_1-h_1)-(p_2-h_2)-(p_3-h_3)}{k-1} 
\end{align*}$$

Is this the correct expansion? According to a couple of numerical solutions that I have tried it works for me. But I just want to be sure before I actually use it.

**Edit:** So this is the correct expansion from what I understand?
$$\begin{align*}F(n,k;h_1,p_1;h_2,p_2;h_3,p_3)=\binom{n-h+k-1}{k-1}+(-1)^1\Bigg(\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_1-h_1)}{k-1}+\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_2-h_2)}{k-1}+\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_3-h_3)}{k-1}\Bigg)+(-1)^2\Bigg(\binom{n-h-(p_1-h_1)-(p_2-h_2)}{k-1}+\binom{n-h-(p_2-h_2)-(p_3-h_3)}{k-1}+\binom{n-h-(p_1-h_1)-(p_3-h_3)}{k-1}\Bigg)+(-1)^3\binom{n-h+k-j-1-(p_1-h_1)-(p_2-h_2)-(p_3-h_3)}{k-1} 
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k=3$, there are $\binom31=1$ $1$-combinations: $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, and $\{3\}$. There are $\binom32=3$ $2$-combinations: $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, and $\{2,3\}$. And there is $\binom33=1$ $3$-combination, $\{1,2,3\}$. For $j=2$, for instance, $k-j-1=0$, so the $\Sigma^*$ expression expands to

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n-h-(p_1-h_1)-(p_2-h_2)}2&+\binom{n-h-(p_1-h_1)-(p_3-h_3)}2\\
&+\binom{n-h-(p_2-h_2)-(p_3-h_3)}2\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the first term is for $\{1,2\}$, the second for $\{1,3\}$, and the third for $\{2,3\}$.

The $j=1$ expansion will also have three terms, while the $j=3$ expansion will have only one.

Comment: So, according to what I understand from your answer. The edit that I have done to the question is the correct expansion?

Comment: @MB_CE: Yes, it looks right.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I thought at first that it might be the expansion that you have suggested. However, the numerical test led me astray. Definitely because of the values that I chose to give the expansion a little try.

Comment: @MB_CE: You’re very welcome.